# Как правильно: охват или обхват?

Tags: выбор-слов

***Охват*** голени или **обхват** голени?

*И как правильно: голень увеличилась **в обхвате (охвате)** на три сантиметра или **обхват (охват)** голени увеличился на три сантиметра?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Охват** — многозначное понятие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82):

> Охват *(экон.)* — количество людей или домохозяйств, которые имеют
>   отношение к какому-либо событию.
>
> Охват *(воен.)* — форма манёвра с целью выхода во фланг группировке
>   противника.
>
> Вертикальный охват *(воен.)* — охват войск противника путём переброски
>   по воздуху аэромобильных, воздушно-десантных или других частей.

Как мы можем убедиться, голень - вне сферы военных или экономических понятий.

Зато **[обхват](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82)** - самое оно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Голень увеличилась в обхвате на три сантиметра.***

---

Культуристу об обхватах:

[Небольшое изменение в обхвате одной только талии приводит к колоссальному изменению всего внешнего вида...](http://athlete.ru/books/think/think2.htm)

Далее по ссылке.